# Display Pictures in Listview - Android

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I've a `ListView` in my app.. The `ListView` can contain text, images or both. If there are images, I want to display the text in the first line and show the set of images in the next line.. Which one should I use?? `ViewFlipper` or `ViewPager` or anything else? I have been looking around for examples on how to do this.

Any pointers would be quite helpful!!

Thanks.

EDIT: I want to display text in the first line and list of Pictures (3-5) in the second line in the listview

Comment: you should go for expandable list view.. try with this http://imobiledevelopment.blogspot.in/2011/06/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Comment: learn how to make a custom listview: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a custom adapter, which I assume you are, then you have to feed some kind of array into it. I don't think you can add another row to a ListView from within the adapter itself, so I would consider parsing through the array, or whatever data you're using to populate your listview. From that, create another array that has a separate entry for the text and image set (if it exists). Then feed that final array into the adapter. Using a JSONArray with JSONObjects might work better because then you can set labels for all the entries.

Then, inside the adapter in the getView() method, check to see if the entry type is text, or images, and change which xml layout it inflates based on that. Or you could use the same xml and control the different views with setVisibility().

If you want to make the images scroll horizontally within their list item, you may have to use a HorizontalScrollView. I haven't ever used it, but I know it might give you some issues with having that scrolling element inside the other scrolling element (the ListView).

Comment: You're spot on :) I'm already making use of JSONArray with JSONObjects and feed the `Listview` with the adapter. The pictures will be dynamic, so I'm planning to create ImageView programatically in getView method.. is that fine?? I tried using ViewPager for swiping Images.. however I had performance problems when I use ViewPager inside Listview.. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Doing ViewPagers in a ListView could be flakey since they both require adapters. I would have two xml layouts that contain the item info, one for text and one for images. That way you don't have to worry about creating the ImageView programatically and messing with all the LayoutParameters garbage in code.

Comment: Could you upvote and accept the answer if this is what you're looking for? Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a ListView with pictures has 3 main parts:
1- creating a simple listview in the main layout

2- creating a custom listview item layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/img"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"/>
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/txt"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then create a custom ListView class:

```
private final Activity context; // the context view of the list
private final String[] countries; // the list of countries
private final Integer[] imageId; // the list of images that you already uploaded to your @Drawable file (res/drawable-xdpi/)
```

a constructor comes after that to create the customView object:

```
//class constructor
public CustomList(Activity context,String[] countries, Integer[] imageId) 
{
super(context, R.layout.list_item, countries);
this.context = context;
this.countries = countries;
this.imageId = imageId;
}
```

The customView class has a getView method that returns the item view:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
txtTitle.setText(countries[position]);
imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
return rowView;
}
```

and finally create the adapter for your list in the mainActivity:

```
 yourList.setAdapter(new CustomList(MainActivity.this, countries, imageId));
```

you can see the full sourceCode and download it here [here](http://www.bourax.com/ismaidro/index.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thx, it's done, but this save time for readers and gives more details and ability to download code.